# Pictures wont become visible

Tags: vb.net

So today in my Computer Programming Class, we created a project called CaseStudy. I saw a way to make the program have more replay value. I decided to morph the code and interface to be like a Hangman game. I've got the limbs to appear, but only after clicking Ok on the messageBox.

I'm wondering if anyone has a way to make these limbs appear in real time.

Here is the important code:

---

```
    Dim SECRET_WORD As String = newSecretWord
        Const FLAG As Char = "!"
        Const GUESS_PROMPT As String = "Enter a letter or " & FLAG & " to guess word:"
        Dim numGuesses As Integer = 0
        Dim letterGuess As Char
        Dim wordGuess As String
        Dim tempWord As String
        Dim endGame As Boolean

        Dim wordGuessedSoFar As String = ""
        Dim lenght As Integer = SECRET_WORD.Length
        wordGuessedSoFar = wordGuessedSoFar.PadLeft(lenght, "_")
        Me.lblSecretWord.Text = wordGuessedSoFar

        Dim tempLetterGuess = InputBox(GUESS_PROMPT, Me.Text)
        If tempLetterGuess = Nothing Then
            endGame = True
        Else
            letterGuess = tempLetterGuess
        End If
        Do While letterGuess <> FLAG And wordGuessedSoFar <> SECRET_WORD And Not endGame
            numGuesses += 1
            For letterPos As Integer = 0 To SECRET_WORD.Length - 1
                If SECRET_WORD.Chars(letterPos) = Char.ToUpper(letterGuess) Then
                    tempWord = wordGuessedSoFar.Remove(letterPos, 1)
                    wordGuessedSoFar = tempWord.Insert(letterPos, Char.ToUpper(letterGuess))
                    Me.lblSecretWord.Text = wordGuessedSoFar


                End If
            Next letterPos


            If wordGuessedSoFar <> SECRET_WORD Then
                tempLetterGuess = InputBox(GUESS_PROMPT, Me.Text)
                If tempLetterGuess = Nothing Then
                    endGame = True
                Else
                    letterGuess = tempLetterGuess
                End If
            End If
        Loop


            If wordGuessedSoFar = SECRET_WORD Then
            MessageBox.Show("You guessed it in " & numGuesses & " guesses!")
        ElseIf letterGuess = FLAG Then
            wordGuess = InputBox("Enter a word: ", Me.Text)
            If wordGuess.ToUpper = SECRET_WORD Then
                MessageBox.Show("You guessed it in " & numGuesses & " guesses!")
                Me.lblSecretWord.Text = SECRET_WORD
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you lose.")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Game over.")
            lblSecretWord.Text = Nothing
        End If

        Dim place As Integer = SECRET_WORD.Length - 1

        If tempLetterGuess <> SECRET_WORD.Chars(place) Then
            numWrong += 1
        End If

        If numWrong = 1 Then
            picHead.Visible = True
        End If
        If numWrong = 2 Then
            picBody.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

---

I can take any other pictures if you'd like.

Comment: You  don't have any *pictures* in your code, so clearly you can't make *pictures* show up. Can you make it more clear what you're asking?

Comment: you can use a Label on the form instead of MessageBox

Comment: The code is not [tag:vbscript].

Comment: Looks like you are writing console mode app code in a gui app.  Too many loops, the one that calls InputBox is the biggest problem.  Sure, that prevents output from being visible, it is stuck in that loop so can't spend the time to paint.  MessageBox is a workaround, it pumps a message loop.  Pretty big structural problem, maybe not a good idea to jump ahead in the class.  It would be done correctly if you used the KeyPress or TextChanged event instead.  Calling the pbox' Update() method is a Q+D workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you want to show your "pictures" before the user sees the message. If so, you need to move the following code to an area just before your `MessageBox` and just after the `InputBox`:

```
    Dim place As Integer = SECRET_WORD.Length - 1

    If tempLetterGuess <> SECRET_WORD.Chars(place) Then
        numWrong += 1
    End If

    If numWrong = 1 Then
        picHead.Visible = True
    End If
    If numWrong = 2 Then
        picBody.Visible = True
    End If
```